# converting a json into another format of json object using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm receiving a JSON from an REST API endpoint in this way:
I have a service connection endpoint defined already from which data will come, but it is not in the desired json format i.e. no children attribute .   Basically each row will have "Request" , "Response" children and rows will be method, path, status, date

```
{
  "journal": [
    {
      "request": {
        "path": "/service/update2/crx",
        "method": "GET",
        "destination": "clients2.google.com",
        "scheme": "https"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Alt-Svc": [
            "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\""
          ],
          "Cache-Control": ["no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"],
          "Content-Encoding": ["gzip"],
          "Content-Security-Policy": [
            "script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-7Sujru4vU7hHy5ukGBGe7A' 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' https: http:;object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/clientupdate-aus/1"
          ],
          "Content-Type": ["text/xml; charset=UTF-8"],
          "Date": ["Tue, 05 Jul 2022 13:21:19 GMT"],
          "Expires": ["Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"],
          "Hoverfly": ["Was-Here"],
          "Pragma": ["no-cache"],
          "Server": ["GSE"],
          "Transfer-Encoding": ["chunked"],
          "X-Content-Type-Options": ["nosniff"],
          "X-Daynum": ["5664"],
          "X-Daystart": ["22879"],
          "X-Frame-Options": ["SAMEORIGIN"],
          "X-Xss-Protection": ["1; mode=block"]
        }
      },
      "mode": "capture",
      "timeStarted": "2022-07-05T18:51:16.990+05:30",
      "latency": 2008.2250020000001
    },
    {
      "request": {
        "path": "/",
        "method": "GET",
        "destination": "www.dsdgarchitects.com",
        "scheme": "https"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Alt-Svc": ["h3=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-29=\":443\"; ma=86400"],
          "Cf-Cache-Status": ["DYNAMIC"],
          "Cf-Ray": ["7260676c7acd7d0f-LAX"],
          "Connection": ["keep-alive"],
          "Content-Encoding": ["br"],
          "Content-Type": ["text/html; charset=UTF-8"],
          "Date": ["Tue, 05 Jul 2022 13:21:29 GMT"],
          "Expect-Ct": [
            "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\""
          ],
          "Host-Header": ["8441280b0c35cbc1147f8ba998a563a7"],
          "Hoverfly": ["Was-Here"],
          "Link": [
            "\u003chttps://www.dsdgarchitects.com/wp-json/\u003e; rel=\"https://api.w.org/\", \u003chttps://www.dsdgarchitects.com/\u003e; rel=shortlink"
          ],
          "Nel": [
            "{\"success_fraction\":0,\"report_to\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":604800}"
          ],
          "Report-To": [
            "{\"endpoints\":[{\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v3?s=a2Cf%2FasVsN82uVMDNlF5ZOFsLL%2BF%2FSb%2ByTAAxgmPH96S7E9UhFouMIHpT2pK99JQPCKYdNGquIUGRIpgDeHNtEv1ay%2Bx8SHcQOJe9jHv92ijjh2osH3kYav2OK5%2F2tFu31gczFZxb%2Bdi\"}],\"group\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":604800}"
          ],
          "Server": ["cloudflare"],
          "Transfer-Encoding": ["chunked"],
          "Vary": ["Accept-Encoding"],
          "X-Httpd": ["1"],
          "X-Proxy-Cache": ["HIT"],
          "X-Xss-Protection": ["0"]
        }
      },
      "mode": "capture",
      "timeStarted": "2022-07-05T18:51:27.144+05:30",
      "latency": 2509.364401
    }
  ],
  "offset": {},
  "limit": {},
  "total": {}
}
```

and what I need is change the JSON into this:

```
  [
    {
      "id": "t1",
      "name": "Recording1",
      "method": "",
      "path": "",
      "status": "",
      "Date":"",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "t1:1",
          "name": "request",
          "method": "GET",
          "path": "/service/update2/crx",
          "status": "",
          "Date": "",
        },
        {
          "id": "t1:2",
          "name": "response",
          "method": "",
          "path": "",
          "status": "200",
          "Date": "Tue, 05 Jul 2022 13:21:19 GMT",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "t2",
      "name": "Recording2",
      "resource": "",
      "start": "",
      "end": "",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "t2:1",
          "name": "request",
          "method": "GET",
          "path": "/",
          "status": "",
          "Date": "",
        },
        {
          "id": "t2:2",
          "name": "response",
          "method": "",
          "path": "",
          "status": "200",
          "Date": "Tue, 05 Jul 2022 13:21:29 GMT",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I've been dealing with this... but I'm not able to find the way to do this properly...
How can I do this in Javascript

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't see the relationship. Where are `t1` and `Recording1` in the original data?

Comment: Is `Date` supposed to be a string or an array? Why do you have `[]` around the dates?

Comment: Any unique id will work and Recording1 and Recording2 can be null. Also, I have edited Date it is a string. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

Map over the `journal` array and copy the appropriate values into the result objects.

You can fill in `id` and `name` using the array index.

```js
const data = {
  "journal": [{
      "request": {
        "path": "/service/update2/crx",
        "method": "GET",
        "destination": "clients2.google.com",
        "scheme": "https"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Alt-Svc": [
            "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\""
          ],
          "Cache-Control": ["no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"],
          "Content-Encoding": ["gzip"],
          "Content-Security-Policy": [
            "script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-7Sujru4vU7hHy5ukGBGe7A' 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' https: http:;object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/clientupdate-aus/1"
          ],
          "Content-Type": ["text/xml; charset=UTF-8"],
          "Date": ["Tue, 05 Jul 2022 13:21:19 GMT"],
          "Expires": ["Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"],
          "Hoverfly": ["Was-Here"],
          "Pragma": ["no-cache"],
          "Server": ["GSE"],
          "Transfer-Encoding": ["chunked"],
          "X-Content-Type-Options": ["nosniff"],
          "X-Daynum": ["5664"],
          "X-Daystart": ["22879"],
          "X-Frame-Options": ["SAMEORIGIN"],
          "X-Xss-Protection": ["1; mode=block"]
        }
      },
      "mode": "capture",
      "timeStarted": "2022-07-05T18:51:16.990+05:30",
      "latency": 2008.2250020000001
    },
    {
      "request": {
        "path": "/",
        "method": "GET",
        "destination": "www.dsdgarchitects.com",
        "scheme": "https"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Alt-Svc": ["h3=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-29=\":443\"; ma=86400"],
          "Cf-Cache-Status": ["DYNAMIC"],
          "Cf-Ray": ["7260676c7acd7d0f-LAX"],
          "Connection": ["keep-alive"],
          "Content-Encoding": ["br"],
          "Content-Type": ["text/html; charset=UTF-8"],
          "Date": ["Tue, 05 Jul 2022 13:21:29 GMT"],
          "Expect-Ct": [
            "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\""
          ],
          "Host-Header": ["8441280b0c35cbc1147f8ba998a563a7"],
          "Hoverfly": ["Was-Here"],
          "Link": [
            "\u003chttps://www.dsdgarchitects.com/wp-json/\u003e; rel=\"https://api.w.org/\", \u003chttps://www.dsdgarchitects.com/\u003e; rel=shortlink"
          ],
          "Nel": [
            "{\"success_fraction\":0,\"report_to\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":604800}"
          ],
          "Report-To": [
            "{\"endpoints\":[{\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v3?s=a2Cf%2FasVsN82uVMDNlF5ZOFsLL%2BF%2FSb%2ByTAAxgmPH96S7E9UhFouMIHpT2pK99JQPCKYdNGquIUGRIpgDeHNtEv1ay%2Bx8SHcQOJe9jHv92ijjh2osH3kYav2OK5%2F2tFu31gczFZxb%2Bdi\"}],\"group\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":604800}"
          ],
          "Server": ["cloudflare"],
          "Transfer-Encoding": ["chunked"],
          "Vary": ["Accept-Encoding"],
          "X-Httpd": ["1"],
          "X-Proxy-Cache": ["HIT"],
          "X-Xss-Protection": ["0"]
        }
      },
      "mode": "capture",
      "timeStarted": "2022-07-05T18:51:27.144+05:30",
      "latency": 2509.364401
    }
  ],
  "offset": {},
  "limit": {},
  "total": {}
};

const result = data.journal.map(({
  request,
  response
}, i) => ({
  id: `t${i+1}`,
  name: `Recording${i+1}`,
  method: "",
  path: "",
  status: "",
  Date: "",
  children: [{
      id: `t${i+1}:1`,
      name: "request",
      method: request.method,
      path: request.path,
      status: "",
      Date: ""
    },
    {
      id: `t${i+1}:2`,
      name: "response",
      method: "",
      path: request.path,
      status: response.status,
      Date: response.headers.Date[0]
    }
  ]
}));

console.log(result);
```